# Is there a way to find out total number of times setInterval() executed for a particular function inside Javascript code using any command

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function say main() which uses setInterval(async()=>{ console.log("Hello")},1000). The function inside setInterval() is executed 13 times i.e. Hello is printing 13 times. I want to check the value or the number of time this setInterval is running. Is there any way to do that?

```
main(){
   setInterval(async()=>{
              console.log("Hello")
              await someApiCall();
              console.log("World");
              await anotherApiCall();
    },1000)
}
```

This main function can be called multiple times. Can that be causing the number of print statement to increase.

Comment: "*Is there any way to do that?*" No. "*This main function can be called multiple times. Can that be causing the number of print statement to increase.*" Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Every time you call `main()` it sets a *new* interval, so yes, it will cause the number of logs to increase. You can keep track of the interval and only set it if it hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Declare a variable in main and count up inside the interval function.

Comment: Thanks, The function is already running on some server so I was looking for some type of command from where I can see the value for debugging. Thanks for responding anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a track of it using some `counter`.

**If you want to keep track of `setInterval` across multiple calls of the `main` function.**

```js
let count = 0;

const main = () => {
  setInterval(async() => {
    console.log("Hello")
    count++
    console.log(count)

  }, 1000)
}

main()
main()
```

**If you want to keep track of `setInterval` within the `main` function.**

```js
const main = () => {
  let count = 0;
  setInterval(async() => {
    console.log("Hello")
    count++
    console.log(count)

  }, 1000)
}

main()
```